# jQuery function containing if's and .each() very slow in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, each

I basically search for an element with specific data-attributes, so I loop through all of the elements with the class that might have those data-attributes. I loop with the jQuery each() function and already read and experienced that it is quite often pretty slow in IE7 or any other IE compared to the other common browsers like Firefox, Chrome or Safari.

Maybe there's a better way to find these elements ?!

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.course', function(){
        var startday = $(this).data('start');
        var endday = $(this).data('end');
        var coursemonth = $(this).data('month');

        $('.dayname').each(function() {
            var thisday = $(this).data('date');
            var thismonth = $(this).data('month');

            if(thisday >= startday && thisday <= endday && thismonth == coursemonth)
            {
                $(this).addClass('red');
            }
        })
});
```

The context I'm looping through with the .each() is a list of days, actually just all the 30 or how many days in a month and this for up to 6 month. Each day contains the date in the format 'mmdd' and also the month as a data attribute.

```
            <div class="dayname we" data-date="0401" data-month="04">So</div>
            <div class="dayname " data-date="0402" data-month="04">Mo</div>
            <div class="dayname " data-date="0403" data-month="04">Di</div>
            <div class="dayname " data-date="0404" data-month="04">Mi</div>
            <div class="dayname " data-date="0405" data-month="04">Do</div>
```

**Update:** Unfortunately all tips and hints to increase the performance of selectors and elements in the each failed. But I still hope to be able to get this to work. I don't really have a proper idea, but I somehow have the feeling that there might be a way with something like find() and a selector that is able to differ between higher and lower numbers as (as you can see in the markup) my data attributes are just numbers. 
Is there a way out there with comparison in the selector ? That way I could omit the .each() and hopefully outrun the performance problem with that.

Comment: I suspect it's the call to `.addClass()` that's making it slow.  IE 7 is pretty dumb about optimizing layout refreshes.

Comment: Don't know if it makes a big difference, but the docs say to avoid multiple `.data` calls. Do `var data = $(this).data();` instead.

Comment: Why do you use `on` on your `body` instead of the `document`?

Comment: If you can find a way to detach `.dayname` elements before you loop through them, it will run faster. Without markup, we can't really give relevant code for that.

Comment: @FelixKling - Change that to `$.data(this)`. No need to create a new jQuery instanse out of `this`.

Comment: I also think that the biggest issue is `$('.dayname')`. IE7 does not have `getElementsByClassName`. So jQuery has to iterate over each node of the document. If you can cache the selected elements or restrict the selector further, this would probably help.

Comment: @FelixKling How would you cache the selected elements for example ? Testing all the suggestions here, will give notice...

Comment: @DanSurfrider well it's not `.addClass()` in particular - it's anything that makes IE think the layout might need to be updated. Also Felix's comment about ".dayname" is probably a good one too - if you know that they're all `<span>` elements, you can use "span.dayname" for example.

Comment: @DanSurfrider - Your best bet would still be to detach it before messing around with it all.

Comment: What the detach would do is prevent IE from re-painting every time you add a class. It usually works really well for things like table sorting/pagination/zebra striping, but i just don't know how your page lays out. You could for example detach an entire content section, perform the .each(), and then attach it back to the page. If the code executes fast enough, you won't see a flicker.

Comment: Yea you should be able to either just detach the divs directly without an each and append them back after, or detatch it's container and do the same.

Comment: @KevinB well I succeeded to detach at least 60% of the unneccessary `'.dayname'`s, but IE still wants to chill out, so I' apparently just have to drop this feature on IE. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can optimize your code to help improve the performance by reducing the number of calls to `data` method and also creating jQuery object instance of `this` element.

```
var $dayName = $('.dayname');
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.course', function(){
        var dataObj = $(this).data();

        $dayName.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var innerDataObj = $this.data();

            if(innerDataObj.date >= dataObj.start 
               && innerDataObj.date <= dataObj.end 
               && innerDataObj.month == dataObj.month)
            {
                $this.addClass('red');
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: I tried all your tips, also combined with some of the other guys gave me and could actually gain *some* performance so thank you for that! But unfortunately it is still not enough to make it bearable. I actually thought of a totally different way of finding these objects...maybe something with .find() ? Do you have any more ideas ?

Comment: @DanSurfrider - Finding the element by class name is very slow in IE<8. If you check my edited answer I have taken the element with class `dayname` into  global variable and using in inside `mouseover` event, I hope that adds some more performance benefit.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can first try to grab a reference to `$(this)` at the top of your function and reuse it.  Calling `$(this)` over and over does have a slight performance impact.
2. Are you able to limit your initial selector scope to something more narrow than just `body`?
3. Do you know if `.course` classes will always be applied to a certain DOM element (e.g. `<p>` tags)?  If you, it seems that IE7's selector searches are faster when you include the tag name in front -- e.g. `p.course` instead of just `.course`.  Link to performance results [here](http://www.componenthouse.com/article-19).

   ```
   $('body').on('mouseenter', '.course', function(){
       var thisObj = $(this),
           startday = thisObj.data('start'),
           endday = thisObj.data('end'),
           coursemonth = thisObj.data('month');

       $('.dayname').each(function() {
           var thisOtherObj = $(this),
               thisday = thisOtherObj.data('date'),
               thismonth = thisOtherObj.data('month');

           if(thisday >= startday && thisday <= endday && thismonth == coursemonth)
           {
               thisOtherObj.addClass('red');
           }
       })
   ```

   });

I hope this helps!

Comment: Tried all your tips, much appreciated. I definitely gained some perfomance, but nearly a second to wait for the actual effect is surely too much. Guess I'll just have to drop IE support for this feature. Thanks a lot! Unless you got any totally different approach to find my elements, maybe with a .find() ?!

Comment: What performance are you seeing on Chrome/FF/Safari?  Just curious if you see similar performance with IE9 -- the javascript engine is supposed to be much improved with that version.  Good luck!

Comment: Well the performance in the other browsers is as expected as if I would just use a standard :hover pseudo css effect, so pretty much instant. I couldn't test IE9 yet, but I also guess it would be quicker than sluggish IE7