# filtering ul li with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, filter

I have 1 ul and in it I have 10000 li
I need to filter them with containing simbols.

I`m using Jquery 2.1.3
and have written this function

```
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        if(!filter){
            $(".wordlist li").slideUp('slow', function(){
                $('.wordlist').css({'border': 'none', 'background': 'transparent'});
            });
            return;
        }
        var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
        $('.wordlist li').each(function(){
            if ($(this).find('.trans').text().search(regex) < 0) {
                $(this).slideUp('slow');
            } else {
                $(this).slideDown('slow');
                count++;
            }
        });
    });
```

this code work fine but
it needs very big time to search with `jquery .each()`

I need function to do this work in minimal time.

can anyone help me?

this is fiddler what I`m doing
https://jsfiddle.net/giasoft/4o84t1fp/

Comment: Does this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8900683/3832970 - help you solve the issue?

Comment: no. it is simillar of my function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thought some points as below:

```
console.log("1:" + new Date().getTime());
var words = $('.wordlist li');// search take time, check this 20 li in 8ms
console.log("2:" + new Date().getTime());
var filter = $("#filter");
var timer = null;
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
    if (timer != null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var filterStr = filter.val(), count = 0;
        console.log(filterStr);
        if(!filterStr){
           words.each(function(){
               $(this).slideDown('slow');
           });
           return;
        }
        var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
        /*below take time too*/
        console.log("3:" + new Date().getTime());
        words.each(function(){
            var ret = $(this).children('.trans').text().search(regex); 
            // children faster than find! or we should store text in array like "words" - words = [{this:this, text: text}], cache those text()
            // some problem here with search, 'A B C' match with 'aaaa'!
            //console.log($(this).children('.trans').text());
            console.log(ret);// 
            if (ret < 0) { 
                $(this).slideUp('slow');
            } else {
                $(this).slideDown('slow');
                count++;
            }
        });
        console.log("4:" + new Date().getTime());
        timer = null;
    }, 500);// do not need search each keyup!

});
```

but the biggest problem is your 10000 li ! In jsfiddle ,  filtering 20 li took 20ms! You can mannually build index for your li  in your script (a large array instead of each(), children() or finde(), but consuming time too) .

Will u build a index (java-lucence or any other things) in your server? You can get data(json/xml format) by $.ajax from your server with keywords(for search) . And also, you can split data into pages! Each $.ajax can be limited with "start" and end. The server side solution seems more than script

slide solution's pseudocode
HTML:

```
<div id=“searchResult” class="main container" style="overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden;">
<ul class="list-group wordlist">
 ….
</ul>
</div>
```

script:

```
 //after keyword changed 
 //query from server, post as a example
 $.post("url", {key:"xxx", skip: skipNum, limit: limitNum}, function(response){
    data = $.toJSON(response); // if your returning data in JSON

    // fade old ul
    $("#searchResult").chidren(".wordlist")
    .animation({"marginLeft": "-xxxpx"}, "fast", "linear", function() {

        //remove old result
        //assume $(this) as $("#searchResult").chidren(".wordlist")
        $(this).remove();
    });

    // assume here after removing old result if above was sync
    // add new ul foreach result in return data
    var newUl = $("<ul>").css({"display", "none", "marging-left": "yyypx"});// hide at first;
    for (var i in data) {
        $("<li>")
         ..... // style , text ,chidren node in li
       .appendTo(newUl);// append to ul
    }
    newUl.appendTo($("#searchResult"));

    //slide the new ul
    newUl.css("display", "block"); //make it display 
    newUl.animation({"marginLeft":"0px"}.....);
}
```

Also, U can do animation with css3

Comment: I need slideup and slidedown animation, becouse I`m trying to do in this way. but also I can search this info in mysql very quickly. but I need animation on the page.

Comment: what about  moving-left-animation with server side solution instead of slidedow and slide up

1 the old search result disappear while moving to left

2 new result appear while moving from right

or sth like one page overlap the other， not using $.each

Comment: I mean animating with <ul> or <div> rather than <li>

Comment: danzeer: can you give me example what you said?

Comment: So as I understand , you advise me to filter this strings in mysql and then with php convert in json array and get in js? so after that I`ll not need filtering with js anymore. Right?

Comment: YES。。。。how brief u got

Comment: the last result is 20ms. very cool.! thank you. AS I sad I filter them in mysql with LIKE and then get with json array in jquery  and after that I animate them. very very good work.

Answer (score 0):

At first, while you are executing following code for each element:

```
if ($(this).find('.trans').text().search(regex) < 0)...
```

this executes 10000 selector query.

To avoid this you can assign data to elements on page load instead of searching content each time

```
$('.wordlist li').each(function() {
  this.word=$(this).find('.trans').text();
});
```

Then replace this selector just with:

```
if (this.word.search(regex) < 0) {
```

Please find it working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mcao0xhy/1/

Also you can assign it to `.data()` instead of object property - that would be much more nice way.

```
$('.wordlist li').each(function() {
  $(this).data('word')=$(this).find('.trans').text();
});
```

And then:

```
if (this.data('word').search(regex) < 0) {
```

Also instead of using each you can create own selector or use already existing one: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/
but this may require some changes in html

Comment: no. it is not working as I need. while the function searching google chrome gives me wait popup. google chrome, opera and mozila is crashing while searching.

Comment: 4:1426709735252 this is console.log result with dfens`s function for 10000 li. can I slidedown one by one while filtering? it will decrease the time.for user